# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, certificate, x509

I am using docker toolbox (quick start terminal and also command prompt)for learning purposes 
and when I run this command I am getting the following error:

**>> docker pull hello-world**

*Using default tag: latest
   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown 
   authority*

getting the error also by logging in by "Docker login".
I am pulling from docker-hub, not any private registry.

Here is what I have done to try to resolve it:

1. I have reinstalled the docker toolbox completely. (uninstalled + deleted files from drives too)
2. used the command. "docker-machine regenerate-certs".
3. created my own self-signed certs (by openssl) and add it properly
4. used the command **>>docker pull hello-world --disable-content-trust.**
5. Disable the TLS image verify
6. Added the trusted registry to the config file.
7. Added the registry to deamon.json in C:/ProgramData/Docker/config/deamon.json.

But nothing works.

***What do I do to get this running again?***

Please clarify, if you need more info on something, please ask.

I have installed as instructed on docker docs.

My System Spec:

processor: i5 8th Gen;

Windows 10 Enterprise x64 bit.

Comment: Are you running this from home or from work environment? If you are using at work you may be facing problems with your company [proxy](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/603). Take a look [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4043) also.

Comment: On [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) document you can find how to configure your proxy on docker for windows.

Comment: Sanket, could you tell me how you solved this please?